# Sum of strings extracted from text file using regex

Tags: python, regex, sum

I am just learning python and need some help for my class assignment.

I have a file with text and numbers in it. Some lines have from one to three numbers and others have no numbers at all.

I need to:

1. Extract numbers only from the file using regex
2. Find the sum of all the numbers

I used regex to extract out all the numbers. I am trying to get the total sum of all the numbers but I am just getting the sum of each line that had numbers.  I have been battling with different ways to do this assignment and this is the closest I have gotten to getting it right.

I know I am missing some key parts but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import re
text = open('text_numbers.txt')

for line in text:
    line = line.strip()
    y = re.findall('([0-9]+)',line)

    if len(y) > 0:
        print sum(map(int, y))
```

The result I get is something like this 
(each is a sum of a line):

> 14151
>
> 8107
>
> 16997
>
> 18305
>
> 3866

And it needs to be one sum like this (sum of all numbers):

> 134058

Comment: Change print sum(map(int, y)) to x += sum(map(int, y)) and at the top before the for loop add x = 0. At the end of the for loop print x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
import np
text = open('text_numbers.txt')
final = []
for line in text:
    line = line.strip()
    y = re.findall('([0-9]+)',line)

    if len(y) > 0:
         lineVal = sum(map(int, y))
         final.append(lineVal)
         print "line sum = {0}".format(lineVal)
 print "Final sum = {0}".format(np.sum(final))
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Ryan. In one of my variations  I had something similar but couldn't get it to work. I had to modify the "import np" to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know much python but I can give a simple solution.
Try this

```
import re
hand = open('text_numbers.txt')
x=list()
for line in hand:
    y=re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
    x=x+y
sum=0
for i in x:
    sum=sum + int(i)
print sum
```

Answer (score 2):

My first attempt to answer with the use of regular expressions, I find it a great skill to practise, that reading other's code.

```
import re # import regular expressions
chuck_text = open("regex_sum_286723.txt")
numbers = []
Total = 0
for line in chuck_text:
    nmbrs = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
    numbers = numbers + nmbrs 
for n in numbers:
    Total = Total + float(n)
print "Total = ", Total
```

and thanx to Beer for the 'comprehension list' one liner, though his 'r' seems not needed, not sure what it does. But it reads beautifully, I get more confused reading two lots of loops like my answer

```
import re
print sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+',open("regex_sum_286723.txt").read())])
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to SO. Code-only answers are discouraged here as they don't teach others how to code. Could you edit your post to explain what your code sample does and how it answers the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = open('text_numbers.txt')
data=text.read()
print sum(map(int,re.findall(r"\b\d+\b",data)))
```

Use `.read` to get content in `string` format

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
sample = open ('text_numbers.txt')
total =0
dignum = 0 

for line in sample:
    line = line.rstrip()
    dig= re.findall('[0-9]+', line)

    if len(dig) >0:
        dignum += len(dig)
        linetotal= sum(map(int, dig))
        total += linetotal

print 'The number of digits are:  ' 
print dignum
print 'The sum is: '
print total     
print 'The sum ends with: '
print  total % 1000
```

Comment: Hope it is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+',open(raw_input('What is the file you want to analyze?\n'),'r').read())])
```

You can compact it into one line, but this is only for fun!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this problem.

```
import re

file = open('text_numbers.txt')
sum = 0 

for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = re.findall('([0-9]+)', line)
    for i in line:
        i = int(i)
        sum += i    

print(sum)
```

The line elements in first **for** loop are the **lists** also and I used second **for** loop to convert its elements to integer from string so I can sum them.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

fl=open('regex_sum_7469.txt')
ls=[]

for x in fl: #create a list in the list
   x=x.rstrip()
   print x
   t= re.findall('[0-9]+',x) #all numbers
   for d in t: #for loop as there a empthy values in the list a
        ls.append(int(d))
print (sum(ls))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
f = open('regex_sum_text.txt', 'r').read().strip()
y = re.findall('[0-9]+', f)
l = [int(s) for s in y]
s = sum(l)
print(s)
```

another shorter way is:

```
with open('regex_sum_text.txt', 'r') as f:
    total = sum(map(int, re.findall(r'[0-9]+', f.read())))

print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print(sum(int(value) for value in re.findall('[0-9]+', open('regex_sum_1128122.txt').read())))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved it

```
import re

hand = open("regex_sum_1778498.txt")
x=list()
for line in hand:
    y = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
if len(y)>1:
    x=x+y

out=list()
    for value in x:
    out.append(float(value))
print(sum(out))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code rather than posting only code.